# MPMusicPlayerController function stop causes crash

Tags: iphone

I use codes below to play ipod audio library.

```
if( musicPlayer==nil)
{

    MPMusicPlayerController* playa=[[MPMusicPlayerController alloc]init];

    musicPlayer=playa;
    [ playa release];
}

 musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
 [musicPlayer setShuffleMode: MPMusicShuffleModeOff];
 [musicPlayer setRepeatMode: MPMusicRepeatModeNone];
 [musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection: userMediaItemCollection];
 [musicPlayer play];
```

when I pressed a button, it will fire function below to stop playing

```
-(void)stopMusicPlayer;
{

   if (playbackState == MPMusicPlaybackStatePlaying) {
        [ musicPlayer stop];
   }    


}
```

but it crash and exit.

Welcome any comment

Thanks
interdev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you released playa and it's dealloced.  If musicPlaya is a retained property, you are only accessing the set message when you use

```
  self.musicPlayer = playa;
```

You did the same thing later with `musicPlayer` -- the method you called returned an autoreleased object.  You need to retain it -- probably by using the set message through `self.musicPlayer` syntax.

The easiest way to find problems like this is to run a Build and Analyze -- I'm pretty sure it would flag playa as being released too many times.  Another good way is by using NSZombiesEnabled which I described how to do on my blog (see Tip #1)

http://www.loufranco.com/blog/files/debugging-memory-iphone.html

UPDATE: to explain further:

You make an instance variable with

```
 MPMusicPlayerController* musicPlayer;
```

and then a property with

```
 @property (retain, nonatomic) MPMusicPlayerController* musicPlayer;
```

Later in your code, you might think that

```
 musicPlayer = playa;
```

is the same as

```
 self.musicPlayer = playa;
```

Because the equivalent thing in Java, C++, and C# (and other languages) is.  It IS NOT the same.

In Objective-C. The @property line generated two messages, getmusicPlayer and setmusicPlayer.  You could use

```
  [self setmusicPlayer: playa]
```

and that would automatically retain playa for you. `self.musicPlayer = playa` is a synonym for that.

Using just `musicPlayer` without self bypasses the set message (and the retain) and just assigns directly to the instance variable.

You can avoid this by doing this instead

```
 @interface ClassName : NSObject
 {
     MPMusicPlayerController* _musicPlayer;
 }

 @property(retain, nonatomic) MPMusicPlayerController* musicPlayer;
```

and then

```
 @synthesize musicPlayer = _musicPlayer;
```

Then, always use `self.musicPlayer` for assignment to make sure to get the retain.  If you accidentally leave off the self, you'll get a compiler error.

Comment: Thanks. But I can not debug on simulator, because I do not how to add music files to audio library on simulator

Comment: I think I have retained in header file:  MPMusicPlayerController  *musicPlayer; 
 
 
@property (nonatomic, retain) MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer;

Comment: Yes, but when you use `musicPlayer` by itself, it doesn't use the property.  To use the automatic retain in the property, you have to use `self.musicPlayer`.  They are not the same (like in other languages) -- ObjC annoyance.